# Rollup: Unresolved Dependencies

Tags: node.js, rollupjs

I'm having issues using npm packages with rollup (specifically lodash).

I'm getting an unresolved dependencies error. I have installed both `rollup-plugin-node-resolve` and `rollup-plugin-commonjs` and configured according to the docs. It's possible I could have missed something obvious.

**Error**

```
[~/Projects/rollup] yarn run build
yarn run v1.2.1
$ rollup -c

src/main.js → ./build/app.js...
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#treating-module-as-external-dependency
loadash (imported by src/main.js)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use options.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
loadash (guessing 'loadash')
created ./build/app.js in 47ms
✨ Done in 0.93s.
```

**src/main.js**

```
import { map } from 'loadash';
console.log('Test');
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/main.js',
  output: {
    file: './build/app.js',
    format: 'iife'
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
      browser: true,
    }),
    commonjs()
  ]
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's called `lodash`, not `loadash`!

Comment: Ha, I wonder why my linter didn't pick that up. A stupid typo on my part.